# SQL: Return only first occurrence

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I seldomly use SQL and I cannot find anything similar in my archive so I'm asking this simple query question: I need a query which one returns **personID** and only the first **seenTime**

**Records:**

```
seenID | personID | seenTime
   108      3         13:34
   109      2         13:56
   110      3         14:22
   111      3         14:31
   112      4         15:04
   113      2         15:52
```

**Wanted result:**

```
personID | seenTime
   3         13:34
   2         13:56
   4         15:04
```

That's what I did & failed:

```
SELECT t.attendanceID, t.seenPersonID, t.seenTime
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY seenID ORDER BY seenID) AS RowNo,
seenID,
seenPersonID,
seenTime
FROM personAttendances) t
WHERE t.RowNo=1
```

P.S: Notice SQL CE 4

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If your seenTime increases as seenID increases:

```
select personID, min(seenTime) as seenTime
from personAttendances
group by personID
```

**Update for another case:**

If this is not the case, and you really want the seenTime that corresponds with the minimum seenID (assuming seenID is unique):

```
select a.personID, a.seenTime
from personAttendances as a
    join (
        -- Get the min seenID for each personID
        select personID, min(seenID) as seenID
        from personAttendances
        group by personID
    ) as b on a.personID = b.personID
where a.seenID = b.seenID
```

Comment: Work great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 21):

You're making it *way* too difficult:

```
select personID, min(seenTime)
from personAttendances
group by personID
```

Answer (score 6):

for [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) there is [DISTINCT ON](https://www.geekytidbits.com/postgres-distinct-on/)

Comment: not all heroes wear capes +1

Comment: this worked for me as well, very simple, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You need to order by seen time not by seen id:

```
PARTITION BY seenID ORDER BY seenTime
```

Answer (score -4):

Add this to your SQL:

```
and where not exists
    (select 1 from personAttendances t2 
    where t.personID=t2.personID 
    and t2.seenID < t.seenID)
```